# Is there a way I can make leaves fall more organically?

Tags: javascript, object, vector, physics, gravity

So, at the moment I'm doing that, but the way my leaves are falling is weird, they're sticking to the same pattern as if they were still all stuck together, I know I could make them a class and give them random magnitude so each one of them would follow it's own path with its own velocity, but I am new to code and don't quite know how to do it, would there be a simpler way??? Thank you in advance (also it'd be nice to know if there is a way to add some time between the sprouting and the falling of the leaves).

```
var leaves = [];

var count = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  var a = createVector (width / 2, height);
  var b = createVector (width / 2, height*3/4);

  tree[0] = root;
}

function mousePressed() {
  count++;

  if (count % 3 === 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
      if (!tree[i].finished) {
        var leaf = tree[i].end.copy();
        leaves.push(leaf);
      }

}



function draw() {
  background(51);

  for (var i = 0; i < leaves.length; i++) {
    fill(255, 204, 100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(leaves[i].x, leaves[i].y, 2.7, 5);
    leaves[i].x += random (0, 1.7);
    leaves[i].y += random (0, 1.5);
  }

}
```

Comment: Make a reproducible example, please! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think it should be better understood now! Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I'm still unable to run your code. There are syntax errors, and definitions for `tree` and `root` are missing. Are you using a framework like Processing or p5.js? Ideally, please provide a link to an online playground where your code can be run easily.

Comment: I don't know what is happening but I'm not able to upload it to the web editor for some reason, my files are not opening there, I can give you maybe a link to the code in github, https://github.com/BruniGui/First-Fractal-Tree/tree/main/FractalTree.v4

Comment: So, finally, it should work now, I just want to thank you in advance for what you're doing, you didn't even get to my question yet but just made me learn a lot about code's text files hehehe, here it is: https://editor.p5js.org/Gui_Bruni/sketches/wAVzT5O-4 

So, I was wondering if there is a way to make these leaves fall correctly instead of just following a straight diagonal line, and maybe if it's possible to include a timer between their sprouting and their fall, by the way, if it is still hard to understand it, just tell me please, I'll do my best to make it clean.

Comment: Start by creating a `Leaf` class, with an `update()` function where you can add the desired behaviours. Generating a random "base" velocity vector for each leaf makes them drift in different directions instead of uniformly. Generating a `wait` time counter and decrementing it in `update()` allows each leaf to fall independently. The constant linear motion approximation is good enough assuming (i) leaves are light (and therefore reach terminal velocity almost instantly), and (ii) the wind speed is uniform and constant.